# retrieving whole paper on basis of paperid

Tags: c#, sql

what i have in database  are tables . what i am doing is saving questions in exam table,  in paper table i have Pid paper name and subject name . i am saving question in exams and this links with the subject question of pid in paper table .. what i am trying is to retrieve the whole question paper .. what i have done so far is

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
     conn.ConnectionString = constring;

     try
     {
         {
               conn.Open();

               string cmdText = cmd;

               SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdText, conn);                          
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
if (questNo > quest_.Rows.Count - 1 || questNo < 0) return;
```

if questNo is 0 and quest_ is empty method will do nothing.

Comment: How about quest_? Does it have records? Did you debug this code? Is required row present in quest_ after calling  sd.Fill(quest_)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String value="";
System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem comboItem = ((System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem)Cmbfilter.SelectedItem);
value = comboItem.Content;
```

Then use *value* in cmdText.

Comment: control.combobox item didnt work its window form app

Comment: I thought you're in wpf. Test this; create a variable as string and try to get value from combobox before try and catch.